# Constructing a large tridiagonal matrix with alternating signs

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

What is the best way to construct a large tridiagonal matrix, in the following form (notably with alternating signs)?

$\mathbf M = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & a & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  \\
  a & 0 & -a & 0 & 0&\cdots \\
  0 & -a & 0 & a & 0 &\cdots \\
  0 & 0 & a & 0 & -a &\cdots \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
 \end{pmatrix}$

I was using code like that shown below to produce constant sign diagonals of $a$ above and below the main diagonal for an $n\times n$ matrix.

```
DiagonalMatrix[Array[a &, n - 1], -1]


DiagonalMatrix[Array[a &, n - 1], 1]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a way using [`Band`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html):

```
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}, {4, 5}] -> {a, -a}, 
          Band[{2, 1}, {5, 4}] -> {a, -a}}, {5, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  a & 0 & -a & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & -a & 0 & a & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & a & 0 & -a \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & -a & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

To make it easier to modify the size and the pattern of elements on the off-diagonals, I'd suggest something like this (incorporating J.M.'s suggestion):

```
With[{n = 7, pattern = {a, -a}},
 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}, {-2, -1}] -> pattern, 
   Band[{2, 1}, {-1, -2}] -> pattern}, {n, n}]]
```

The negative indices are counted from the end, so that we don't need to use the dimension `n` in the `Band` specification. The reason I specify the beginning *and* end of each band is that only in this case will a cyclic repetition of `pattern` occur, as desired. If the end specification is omitted, `pattern` will only be used to fill the first few entries of the `Band`.

Comment: Very efficient.  Elegant.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use negative indices on the second argument of `Band[]`: `SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}, {-2, -1}] -> {a, -a}, Band[{2, 1}, {-1, -2}] -> {a, -a}}, {7, 7}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, I'll include that -

Answer (score 6):

Here are two alternatives to Jens's procedure.

With `Band[]`:

```
With[{n = 7, a = 1}, 
     SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> #, Band[{2, 1}] -> #}] & @
     PadRight[{}, n - 1, {a, -a}]]
```

Without `Band[]`:

```
With[{n = 7, a = 1}, 
     SparseArray[{{j_, k_} /; Abs[j - k] == 1 && EvenQ[Max[j, k]] -> a,
                  {j_, k_} /; Abs[j - k] == 1 && OddQ[Max[j, k]] -> -a}, {n, n}]]
```

Both should yield

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `DiagonalMatrix` easily as well:

```
n = 7; 
DiagonalMatrix[-a*(-1)^Range[n - 1], -1] + DiagonalMatrix[-a*(-1)^Range[n - 1], 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

```
fun[n_, a_] := SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 :> a (-1)^(i - 1),
   {i_, j_} /; j == i - 1 :> a (-1)^(i)}, {n, n}]
```

e.g.

```
Grid[Partition[(fun[#, a] // MatrixForm) & /@ Range[2, 10], 3]]
```

[image]

See comments from J.M. nicer first condition: 
`{i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 :> a (-1)^j`

Comment: You could have done `{i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 :> a (-1)^j` instead. ;)

Comment: @J.M. yes that is neater...should have thought a bit more.  Will edit with appropriate attribution :)

Comment: Oh my, that was only for the superdiagonal; your expression for the subdiagonal was fine as it was.

Comment: @J.M. I am not well atm...will correct my blunder...you saved characters based on parity change (j=i+1, has same parity as i-1)...as I said not well....